# react-router-dom blank screen when routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm poking around with react routing and can't get it to work. I've stripped down to an empty new project just to test the fundamentals, and still can't get it running. I am using vscode and generated my react project using npx. This is my current code:

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import Landing from './components/Landing'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Landing />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

My landing.js is just a text entry, which I have confirmed does work if there is no BrowserRouter wrapper.

I've tried:

- Adding `<h1>Hello</h1>` within `<BrowserRouter>` to see if it would render prior to the Routes -- it did not.
- Varying syntaxes (component vs element keyword, different paths)
- Leaving `index.js` as default and doing routing in `App.js`
- Leaving `App.js` as default and doing routing within the render function in `index.js`

All of the resources I've found online for react-router-dom@6 points that this (or some iteration of what I've done) is correct, yet I get a blank screen no matter what I do once I wrap within `<BrowserRouter>`.

Any help would be invaluable at this point; I don't think I'll be able to continue on my own.

Comment: The code looks fine to me, I don't see any issue with it. It also runs as expected here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-blank-screen-when-routing-0y0uso?file=/src/App.js). How are you running your app? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Running through vscode, I cd to my working directory and initiate with `npx create-react-app bin` . Then, `npm install react-router-dom`. I've tried running through either `npm start` and as doing a dedicated build. 

`node --version` returns v16.17.0

Perhaps some reinstall of the underlying framework would be the next step?

Comment: After creating the project with `npx create-react-app bin` the next step should be to cd into the bin directory and run `npm install` to install dependencies, *then* `npm i -s react-router-dom` to install `react-router-dom` *and* save it to your package.json file, *then* run `npm start` to run the app. I think the node version installed should be fine.

Comment: That did it! The nuance of local dependencies is something I never really learned through all my time on colab with Python. I figured since my terminal wasn't throwing any errors when I started that there was no dependency issues. I'll do some reading up on this kind of thing now that I'm more aware of it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the project with `npx create-react-app bin` the next step should be to `cd` into the bin directory and run `npm install` to install dependencies, *then* `npm i -s react-router-dom` to install `react-router-dom` *and* save it to your package.json file, *then* run `npm start` to run the app. I think the node version installed should be fine.

Steps:

1. Create project: `npx create-react-app bin`
2. Change into the project directory: `cd bin`
3. Install project dependencies: `npm i`
4. Add `react-router-dom` to the project: `npm i -s react-router-dom`
5. Edit code & save
6. Run the project: `npm start`